# How to solve this plot error (Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ)?

Tags: r

Hello Im trying to draw a plot on R and I have an error which is

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
> 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

and here is my code

```
lambda= 1.75
K1 = 1000
N = c(1)


for (t in 1:75) {
  N = c(N,tail(N,1)*(1+lambda)*(1-log(tail(N,1))/log(K1)))
  
}
plot(t,N,
     col="blue",type = "o",
     ylim = c(0,max(N)),
     xlab = "Time", ylab = "Popu" )
`
```

Comment: I tried but still the same error appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `t` takes a single value for each iteration of the loop. After the loop it has the single value `75`, whereas `N` is a length 76 vector (the starting value of 1 plus one value for each iteration in the loop.

Therefore you could do:

```r
plot(0:75, N,
     col = "blue", type = "o",
     ylim = c(0, max(N)),
     xlab = "Time", ylab = "Popu")
```

[image]